# How to reverse the String?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

how to reverse the String without using any API like `reverse()` , `length()` , `toCharArray()` , `charAt()`

Comment: If you can't use any methods, then you can't do anything with the string, unless you use reflection...

Comment: Good story. What is your question?

Comment: Use `StringBuffer` ;)

Comment: Indeed, you may use reflection in order to hack the `String` instance and reach the private field `char[] value`. This is the character array that a `String` object actually wraps. Nevertheless, you will not be able to operate on the same `String` instance, as this private field is also final.

Comment: If they asked this in an interview, then you don't want the job. Unless the answer they're looking for is: "Why on earth would I do that?"

Comment: Don't get panic. The amount of down votes showing anger on your interviewer.

Comment: Is `substring` also part of `any API like:...`? (just asking :D)

Comment: @gyabraham How to reverse a string without using any API. How hard is it to see that from the question?

Comment: @AliAlamiri The question "?" characters nor any details on asker's intentions, but let's move on. The interviewer tried to check his/her knowledge on core java stuffs (immutability of the String class) and some algorithmic skills (write a method that produces the reverse copy of a String)

Comment: @gyabraham ali is not the asker.

Comment: @gyabraham You thinking that I am the OP just shows the lack of attention you have for this question :).

Comment: @JavaAddict Can you define `any API like`? Do you mean any API of `String`/`StringBuilder`/`StringBurrer`?

Comment: @AliAlamiri Sorry I corrected my comment

Comment: it is possible with java.nio.CharBuffer

Comment: "like" here needs to be **way** more specific. In Java, you can't do **anything** with a `String` without using "an API method" (which I presume is what you meant) (except assign it to another `String`, which isn't particularly useful here) **even if** you use reflection (those are also methods). Well, perhaps you could call a constructor (those don't technically classify as methods), but again you won't be left with many choices from there without using methods.

Comment: see https://interviewquizandanswers.blogspot.com/2020/04/reverse-string.html

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to print reversed string then you can add [Right-to-left override](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%E2%80%AE) character before it like

```
public static void printReversed(String s){
    System.out.println("\u202E"+s);
}
```

usage

```
printReversed("Abc");
```

Output on console supporting Unicode

```
‮Abc
```

Comment: That's very nice indeed ;-) I hope that's not what the interviewer expected though!

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection to modify the underlying char[] array. But that would be a huge hack.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: `gnirtS eht`. You could also consider using a char array yourself. So, not using any classes at all.

```
char[] c = {'t', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'S', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'};
for (int i = 0; i < c.length / 2; ++i)
{
    char k = c[i];
    c[i] = c[c.length - i - 1];
    c[c.length - i - 1] = k;
}
```

Or (warning, no international support):

```
byte[] c = "the String".getBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < c.length / 2; ++i)
{
    byte k = c[i];
    c[i] = c[c.length - i - 1];
    c[c.length - i - 1] = k;
}
String result = new String (c);
```

Comment: That's not a string, it's a char[]...

Comment: Fixed it :P Not using any method that isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative regex based answer. Two steps:

- Bruteforce the length by matching against ., .., ...
- Build a regex that replaces (.)(.)(.) with $3$2$1 according to the length

Code

```
String input = "Hello";
// brute force the length
int length = 0;
String dots = null;
do {
    length++;
    dots = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dots += ".";
    }
} while (!input.matches(dots));

// build reversing regex
StringBuilder capture = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder replace = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    capture.append("(.)");
    replace.append("$");
    replace.append(length - i);
}
input = input.replaceFirst(capture.toString(), replace.toString());
System.out.println(input);
```

Comment: +1: I lolled on the regex dot approach :P

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can manage without reverse() , length() , toCharArray() , charAt() is this using split() on the empty string to get a character array, then reverse concatenation.

```
public class StackOverflow21023506 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "";
        for (String each : "Hello".split("")) {
            result = each + result;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output

```
olleH
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the spirit of the question is talking about the whole api or just those methods. It seems odd to be allowed to split on empty, but not allowed to `toCharArray`.

Comment: @ZouZou A really bad idea unless using a character encoding where 1 byte = 1 char...

Answer (score 1):

I'm considering this as a kind of challenge, so here is a worse attempt:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "qmsfdj";
    String result = "";
    try
    {
        int i = 0; 
        while (true)
        {
            result = str.substring(i, i + 1) + result;
            ++i;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Was going to post similar solution but since we can't use `charAt` then why could we use `substring`. Most problematic word in OP is "like" in `any API like` sentence.

Comment: Yeah, the interviewer was probably dumb. Asking him to reverse a `java.lang.String` without using anything af the API. Well, that is just bullshit. Even reflection is part of the API.

Comment: True. Only reflection seems to be tool not involved with String API. It seems that interviewer didn't want to hire OP :/

Comment: I am just wondering if JNI or connections to other apps (not necessary written in Java - so they will not use `charAt()` :D ) is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Regexp to the rescue! The idea is to replace the first character with the last and recursively everything in between them with the reversed content.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Reverse {

    private static final Pattern REVERSER = Pattern.compile("^(.)(.*)(.)$",
                                                            Pattern.DOTALL);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverse(args.length == 0 
                                   ? "Why am I doing this?"
                                   : args[0]));
    }

    public static String reverse(String s){
        Matcher m = REVERSER.matcher(s);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(3) + 
                                    reverse(m.group(2)) + 
                                    m.group(1));
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello world!";
        CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap(str);
        int len = cb.limit();
        String rev = "";
        while (len-- > 0) rev += cb.get(len);
        System.out.printf("[%s]\n", rev);
    }
}
```

then

```
$ javac Reverse.java && java -ea Reverse
[!dlrow olleh]
```